# mysql - get average of the difference between two data cells

Tags: mysql

I have a table of MySQL data. Each row has its own data. In that row there is `start_time` and `end_time`. Basically, when you started doing an objective and when you finished (inserted into the database). Like a timer of sorts.

How would I get the average of of taking the unix timestamp of `start_time` and `end_time`. I know you would minus the `end_time` by `start_time` to get the difference (in milliseconds?) and from there... not sure what else.

Comment: Maybe the average function will be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`unix_timestamp`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) of a date column returns its representation as seconds from the epoc, so subtracting two of these will give a difference in seconds. Like any other number, you can apply the aggregate [`avg`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) function to it in order to get an average:

```
SELECT AVG (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time))
FROM   my_table
```

Once you have this result, you could manipulate it in any way you like. One useful manipulation would be to use [`sec_to_time`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) to convert a number of seconds to a HH:MM:SS format (e.g., 183 seconds would be represented as 00:03:03 hours):

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME 
       (AVG (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)))
FROM   my_table
```